# Problem with session in Django after login

Tags: django, session

Hi am relatively new to Django, been making steady progress with most of the stuff but i have come to be stuck at the sessions part. 
After i login from my login view, it is successful and redirects to the next link which points to another view. This is where the problem happens, request.user simply returns an empty object and my user not detected as logged in. 
I tried googling everywhere and reading the official django tutorials but can't come up with anything, can anybody look at my code to see where i did wrong? I also looked at my database and it seems django is correctly storing sessions on my database, could this be something wrong with the cookies?

Below is my 2 simple views.

def mylogin(request):

```
def errorHandle(error): 
    form = LoginForm() 
    return render_to_response('login/login.html', { 
                                             'error' : error, 
                                             'form' : form, 
    }) 
if request.method == 'POST': # If the form has been submitted... 
    form = LoginForm(request.POST) # A form bound to the POST data 
    if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass 
        username1 = request.POST['username'] 
        password1 = request.POST['password']
        u = User.objects.get(username=username1) 
        user = authenticate(username=username1, password=password1) 
        if user is not None: 
            if user.is_active: 
                # Redirect to a success page. 
                login(request, user)
                username1 = user.last_name + " " + user.first_name              
                return HttpResponseRedirect("../portal/")
                #return render_to_response('login/logged_in.html', {
                #    'username': username1,
                #},RequestContext(request)) 
            else: 
                # Return a 'disabled account' error message 
                error = u'account disabled' 
                return errorHandle(error) 
        else: 
            # Return an 'invalid login' error message. 
            error = u'invalid login' 
            return errorHandle(error) 
    else: 
        error = u'form is invalid' 
        return errorHandle(error) 
else: 
    form = LoginForm() # An unbound form 
    return render_to_response('login/login.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

def mytest(request):

```
request.user.username
return render_to_response('login/logged_in.html', {
                    'username': username1,
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're reinventing the wheel unnecessarily - all this heavy lifting has already been done. I strongly recommend using [django-registration](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-registration/) for this, possibly in conjunction with  [django-profiles](https://bitbucket.org/ubernostrum/django-profiles). The documentation is a bit abstract but it's extremely well written and very flexible. I never deploy a Django site without it, and never grapple with issues like this one.

Comment: Even without registration or profile, Django has user login out-of-the-box, so there is no need to rewrite it.

Comment: Ah, i was just going with the django documentation trying to understand how things work since this is what was given on the site(almost). Thanks anyway, i will try registration

Comment: Hmmm i am not really writing up my own login, i am just  generating a form for user login, as you can see i am actually using django's authenticate and user login in my form, it just puzzles me why there is no session after i login with this form. Also i am not really looking to do any registration, i just wanted a simple login from the user in order to view certain contents on the site.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know why your sessions are expiring. I understand that you're not trying to do registration right now, but django-registration does handle login, password recovery etc. for you. And it gives you all the tools you need to expand your registration/login/logout etc. in the future as you grow. Sorry I couldn't help with your actual question.